# Passing value when select box change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I got a question regarding passing the value of the select option to my XML parser. First look at my code:

**HTML**

```
<table id="ProfileList">
    <tr>
        <td>session</td>
        <td>timestamp</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<select>
  <option value="none">--select user--</option>  
  <option value="user20">user20</option>
  <option value="user30">user30</option>
  <option value="user40">user40</option>
  <option value="user50">user50</option>
</select>
```

As you can see I have a select box with 5 options were only the last four are important.

**Javascript**

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var user = $(this).val();
    alert($(this).val());

    //Sample XML    
    var user20 = "<?xml version='1.0' ?><results><row><session>21</session><time>2014-02-28 21:12:12</time></row><row><session>176763</session><time>2014-03-01 14:04:35</time></row></results>";

    var user30 = "<?xml version='1.0' ?><results><row><session>26</session><time>2014-02-28 21:12:12</time></row><row><session>176763</session><time>2014-03-01 14:04:35</time></row></results>";

    //Parse the givn XML
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( user ); 

    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);


    var $row = $xml.find("row");
    $row.each(function(){

        var session = $(this).find('session').text(),
            time = $(this).find('time').text();
        $("#ProfileList" ).append('<tr><td>' +session+ '</td>' + '<td>' +time+ '</td></tr>');

    });
});
```

What I want is that the value of my select option is used as input for my XML parser. If I run this code, then I will get an error that the XML is invalid.

To clarify: If I set a fixed value then it works:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( user20 );
```

But if I want to set it variable it does not work:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( user );
```

Can anyone tell me why this is and perhaps how I could solve this?

[DEMO CAN BE FOUND HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uL2mpskf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an object containing the XML samples and access each XML by its property name of the object, see http://jsfiddle.net/3po6xgmt/ which does

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var user = $(this).val();
    alert($(this).val());

    //XML samples
    var samples = {
        user20 : "<?xml version='1.0' ?><results><row><session>21</session><time>2014-02-28 21:12:12</time></row><row><session>176763</session><time>2014-03-01 14:04:35</time></row></results>",
        user30 : "<?xml version='1.0' ?><results><row><session>26</session><time>2014-02-28 21:12:12</time></row><row><session>176763</session><time>2014-03-01 14:04:35</time></row></results>"
    };

    //Parse the given XML
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( samples[user] ); 

    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);


    var $row = $xml.find("row");
    $row.each(function(){

        var session = $(this).find('session').text(),
            time = $(this).find('time').text();
        $("#ProfileList" ).append('<tr><td>' +session+ '</td>' + '<td>' +time+ '</td></tr>');

    });
});
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect Solution! Thanks for helping me! :)